# RxJava throwing an exception or using onError

Tags: rx-java

Is there any way to decide whether an exception should be thrown by a method returning rxjava type or should be propagated through onError?
If I have a method that should throw NPE if the argument is null, should this exception be thrown by the method itself or through the observable/flowable returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a best practice, you should always propagate the error through `onError`. Otherwise, someone calling your method like this will end up not handling the exception properly:

```
public void doStuff() {
  someMethodReturningCompletable()
      .andThen(yourMethodThatThrows(argument))
      .subscribe(v -> { /* success */ }, err -> { /* this won't get called */);
}
```

If your method throws and exception immediately if `argument` is null, two bad things happen:

1. You throw it before the `subscribe` call is even executed, and possibly before `someMethodReturningCompletable()` is actually executed (since it hasn't been subscribed to yet).
2. The exception doesn't get propagated downstream, it just is thrown into `doStuff()`, and it isn't set up to handle that.

Comment: What if it does not make sense to execute the whole stream of operators if the argument is invalid? If I have, for example, an observable that returns the user from database based on the id given in the method and the id is null, is it still bad to throw the exception from the method?

Comment: @Barracuda Yes. What I would do is wrap your whole method body in `Observable.defer(() -> { ...})` That way you can keep your existing code that throws the Exception, but now it will be caught by the `defer` call in propagated downstream.

Comment: @Barracuda If you're really worried about the overhead of calling a chain of operators to propagate the error, you can also use an if/else statement to return `Observable.error(new NullPointerException())` if `id` is null, or executes your normal chain if its not.

Comment: I just think of propagating exceptions through observable as throwing checked exceptions -- giving the client the ability to recover from them, whereas unchecked exception are meant for programming errors - to indicate that there is a programming error in the code. Because I think now that if I propagate it through the observable and the subscriber does not react on it(they just have onNext lambda), what happens then? Isn't is going to be swallowed? Or is it propagating an exception through observable on which no one reacts the same as throwing it from that method?

Comment: If there's no `onError` handler in the caller's `subscribe`, a `OnErrorNotImplementedException` will be emitted in the global `onError` handler registered from the application (or to the default one, if no custom one is registered). See https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling for more info (though that page is a bit out of date). Some more up-to-date info can be found here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling

Answer (score 0):

The way I think about it is: `onError` belongs to the stream, so it should notify about errors related to the stream. The argument of a method which returns a stream is part of the method's contract, not part of the stream itself.

Said another way: an issue *creating* the stream is not the same as an issue of *execution* of the stream.

So why should a violation of the method's contract go into the stream? I don't see an issue in checking that arguments respect some preconditions when the method is called and throwing an exception if they are violated.

Plus, this is also how many RxJava methods work, e.g. `Observable.just` and `Observable.range`.